# Retrieve records by date laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I have several records in a model, and want to be able to retrieve them by date. My url looks like this:

`Nov-01-2017/answers` and is generated with the following:

`/{{$date->format('M-d-Y')}}/answers"`

The `created_at` format looks like: `2017-11-01 16:58:04`.

My controller looks like this:

`$record = $record->where('created_at', '=', $date)->get();`

It won't retrieve the records and I'm sure it's something to do with my date formatting but any advice on how to retrieve records based on the created_at date would be helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$record = $record->whereDate('created_at', 
      Carbon::createFromFormat('M-d-Y', $date)->toDateString())->get();
```

So you create carbon based on given format and then you change this into valid string in `Y-m-d` format.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
$record = $record->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d', $date))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Ended up going with the solution below, but also helpful :)